# What's the difference between "at its time" or "of its time"?

Tags: prepositions

1. > It's far more popular than the books published **at** its time.
2. > It's far more popular than the books published **of** its time.

Could you please tell me the difference between the two, and the correct usage?

Comment: I'm having trouble thinking of a context "at its time" would work in, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. Can you [edit] to include some examples of sentences these would be used in?

Comment: It's far more popular than the books published at its time.

Answer (score 1):

It was far more popular than other similar books  published **in** its time.

It was the most controversial book **of** its time.

It was published in 1921 and was not an expensive book **at** the time, but owing to the small number of copies produced, and its subsequent notoriety, it is now impossible to find for under $5000.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a meaning of "at its time". "Of its time" means that what your are talking about is appropriate for the period that it existed, for example one might say

> Ham house is true example of its time.

You can also suggest that something is "ahead of its time" meaning it was very progressive or innovative compared to other things of the same period.

For some reason, the reverse expression acquires an s: "behind the times".